# Spring 3 link to external javascript halts execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using spring 3 and I have jquery added to my project. Now I am attempting to use the jquery number spinner plugin found at https://github.com/jogep/jquery.ui.spinner

The problem is, when I link to the external javascript file, it seems to hault all other javascript after the script inport. see below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/starburst/resources/jqueryNumberSpinner/ui.spinner.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("woi");
    });
</script>
```

It cannot be an error in the script itself because I have the example working on my local machine using the exact same js file. If I delete the import for ui.spinner.js shown above, I get the alert showing up as it should. I am completely baffeled by this, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: I am also using dojo in the project and I included the scripts **after** the dojo include statements.

[image: Firebug screenshot for scripts on the page]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Have you checked with Fiddler that the external file is downloaded correctly?

Comment: I used firebug on firefox and the script is on the page, everything seems fine, but if i run that code, no alert displays. It does not reach the document.ready function

Comment: Well I don't know about Dojo and jQuery interoperability. Maybe the "ready" status of the document trapped by jQuery could be overridden somehow by Dojo. I'm not a Dojo Jedi, though. Anyways It could be the same problem with the jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to find a solution, for the benefit of others. I am not sure if its spring specific but here goes ,

```
<spring:url var="spinnerJsUrl" value="/resources/jqueryNumberSpinner/ui.spinner.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/">
<!-- required for FF3 and Opera -->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${spinnerJsUrl}">
<!--testing here-->
</script>   

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.spinner').spinner({ min: 0, max: 100 });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 quick things to check out:

1) is jQuery core script already linked somewhere within the same page or imported header before the inclusion of ui.spinner.js?

2) is the path you indicated in the `<script>` tag effectively reachable from this page?

Anyways, if you use Chrome or Firefox with FireBug you could access to the JavaScript console to see a more detailed explanation of the error (e.g.: for Chrome you can access the console with shift+ctrl+i, while on mac it is command-option-i; on Firefox you can activate FireBug). There is something similar on IE 8+ also, with F12 if memory assists me.

Hth.

Comment: Yes, i did include the jquery my spring 3 loadscripts file and the script is reachable, however my document ready script is not displayed in the DOM layout shown on firebug. Above is a screenshot of the imports

Comment: It seems a little weird to me that your page includes a first version of jQuery (1.4.3) and then a more recent one (1.6.2). Anyways I'm proceeding with the analysis.